# Idenfifying when a object is created using unsafe.allocateInstance()

Tags: java, performance

Just trying to learn on sun.misc.Unsafe low-level java operations. I was reading [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/10/19/usage-of-class-sun-misc-unsafe/) article however, my question is related to advantages of using Unsafe.

In this example, `Player p = (Player) unsafe.allocateInstance(Player.class);` Where is the object created? On JVM heap or non-heap direct memory?

Are all the operations that are explained in the article non-heap allocations? I ask this because, when you use “new” key-word, its supposed to create an instance on the heap. If it does, then what is the actual advantage, because then, it doesnt by-pass the GC.

Comment: *Read* the article: "This creates an instance of player class without any initialization .. Even if you create this constructor private;  You can initialize using Unsafe.allocateInstance()". It's naught to do with "performance" or where the "allocation is" at all.

Comment: having read the article it didn't seem that the point was to by-pass the GC. For further reading http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

Comment: Exactly, because that *isn't* the point of `allocateInstance`.

Comment: @user2864740 I think its clear now (after digging a bit more on this) that allocateInstance() is for native memory and not heap and also wont initialize the class constructor.

Comment: @Ashley Nope, not so! Both `new` *and* `allocateInstance` allocate the memory "on the heap" and return a reference to the object "on the heap". The difference is that `allocateInstance` *skips any initialization* - this means the constructor *is not called* and any in-line assignments in variable declarations *do not occur*. However, *it has no effect on where the memory is allocated* - the object returned from both approaches is handled by the GC.

Comment: @Ashley If you want "off heap" (non GC) memory, use `allocateMemory`. But *do not* confuse this with `allocateInstance` - the simple memory allocation method is *not associated* with an instance. (A case where `allocateInstance` may be used is for deserialization when, for whatever means, the constructor must be skipped.)

Answer (score 3):

Method `Unsafe#allocateInstance(Class<?>)` will allocate only memory in the heap, whithout initialization phase. By next [link](http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/) described that this method avoid initialization paragraph. You can also review [openJDK thread](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/question-about-Unsafe-allocateInstance-td23595.html) where this question is also disscuessed.

You can allocate non-heap memory using method Unsafe#allocateMemory(long). You can also review example of usage in [DirectByteBuffer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/DirectByteBuffer.java#DirectByteBuffer.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29) class, which created by [ByteBuffer#allocateDirect(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29).

If you want to work with non-heap memory consider using [ByteBuffer allocateDirect](http://www.kdgregory.com/?page=java.byteBuffer). But actual advantage of using non-heap memory is  doubtful. You should make performance benchmarks to be sure you have performance advantage. Also consider using  [-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm#BABGCFFB) parameter to force native memory reusing if you use direct buffers.

Comment: Thanks @Taky for clearing this up and the new link. Its great help. Now, using DirectByteBuffer is great, however, DirectByteBuffer uses Unsafe internally. So, I am trying to check the range of functionality that can be achieved by Unsafe for various operations. It seems we can achieve a certain amount of GC-less programming using Unsafe. Thanks again.

Comment: I would disagree that allocate deals with the heap. I have created and run programs by setting memory off-heap using this and now its pretty clear that off-heap memory is used here. There are some other things I am looking to clarify in terms of some auxiliary operations that are performed along with using Unsafe, however, the concepts are getting more clear now.

Comment: The easiest way to check whether object in the heap is to allocate instances with your hypothesis method, make heap dump with jmap and review objects with MAT.

Comment: I take it back as I wrongfully mixed up allocateInstance() with allocateMemory().